# BackboneJS error TypeError: model.parse is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm upgrading from Backbone v0.9.2 to 0.9.10 and, when trying to fetch a model from a router, get this error:

```
TypeError: model.parse is not a function
if (!model.set(model.parse(resp, options), options)) return false;
```

It fetches the model from the server just fine, but then blows up on that.

Using: latest BackboneJS, latest UnderscoreJS, latest backbone-support(from thoughtbot), jQuery 1.8.3, Rails backend

Here is the relevant code:

```
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/users'
});

App.Collections.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: App.Models.User,
  url: '/users'
});

App.Routers.Users = Support.SwappingRouter.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new App.Collections.Users();
    this.el = $('div[role="main"]');
  },

  routes: {
    '!/users/:id' : 'show'
  },

  show: function(userId) {
    var user = new App.Models.User({ id: userId });
    user.fetch();
    // ...more code
  }
});

var App = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  initialize: function() {
    new App.Routers.Users();
    if (!Backbone.history.started) {
      Backbone.history.start();
      Backbone.history.started = true;
    }
  };
```

Would it have anything to do with the fact that I have a Rails(3.2.10) backend? http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

Edit:
Here's my Rails controller action

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    @user = find_user params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render json: @user }
      format.html { redirect_to '/#!/users/' + params[:id] }
    end
  end
```

Comment: It's telling you pretty clearly that `model.parse` is not a function. You're invoking `model.parse`. It's not a function. This has nothing to do with your server-side Rails code. What is `model`? Where are you defining it?

Comment: That is from the backbone source (development), line 419

Comment: I am having the same problem with backbone ( but I am not using Rails..only CouchDB + Backbone )